# why does javascript `for` loop rapidly mute/unmute video

Tags: javascript, loops, electron, html5-video

I have an in-house `electron` app for playing videos with filters. Source code [here](https://github.com/BYU-ODH/electron_player). On most computers, the code works flawlessly, but on the booth computer where the video is shown to a class of students, when a `mute` filter is applied, the  `player.mute()` and `player.unmute()` rapidly alternate many times per second. This only happens for some of the `mute` filters on some movies on some computers. I need help to track down the source of the problem.

The relevant part for this question (I think) is in [script.js, lines 224-258](https://github.com/BYU-ODH/electron_player/blob/1fb5c8fcbb5f99b21a0310c3201576554ff94ea3/script.js#L224-L258).

```
        for (var i = 0; i < numAnnotations; i++) {
          var vMuted = player.video_obj.muted
          var vBlanked = player.video_obj.classList.contains('blanked')
          var vBlurred = player.video_obj.classList.contains('blurred')

          var a = player.annotations[i]
          var aStart = a['start']
          var aEnd = a['end']
          var aType = a['type']
          var aDetails = a['details']

          switch (a['type']) {
            case 'skip':
              if (time >= aStart && time < aEnd) {
                console.log('skipped to '+Number(aEnd).toFixed(3))
                player.skip_to(aEnd)
              }
              break
            case 'mute':
            case 'mutePlugin':
              if (currently.muting === -1 || currently.muting === i) { //if no annotation is currently muting or *this* current annotaiton is muting
                if (time >= aStart && time < aEnd) { //if within annotation time
                  if (!vMuted) {
                    console.log('mute on')
                    currently.muting = i
                    player.mute()
                  }
                } else {
                  if (vMuted) {
                    console.log('mute off')
                    currently.muting = -1
                    player.unmute()
                  }
                }
              }
```

This code usually works flawlessly, but it sometimes fails at very inconvenient times. What is the source of the problem, or how can I debug it myself?

Comment: example media files can be found in the [kung-test folder](https://github.com/BYU-ODH/electron_player/tree/master/kung-test). Launch the player and select the three files in that folder (excluding the `.bak` file). Sometimes the mute from 52-55 seconds will result in rapid muting/unmuting.

Comment: using electron version `2.0.9`

Comment: Does not appear to be deterministic. I added logging of `currentTime` when this happens, and every time I run it, the times are slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was only with videos that were not the first one loaded after launching the player. We were able to track down that we were getting multiple eventListeners that were fighting with each other. We just had add to add a tracker to only add event listeners when they didn't already exist.